# Javascript documentation notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, documentation

I've seen this a lot and most of the time I can figure out what it means, but there have been times when I was a bit confused. Looking at documentation mostly on jquery i see something like this:

`.toggleClass( function [, state ] )`

what does the bracket notation with the comma and `state` mean exactly?

Any info would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: It means they optional parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything between the brackets `[]` is optional.

In your case it means that `state` can be omitted, and the function will still work.

Answer (score 1):

**Optional  parameters.**

Those marked inside such as `state` in your case can be omitted and the function will not throw an error.

For another example:

> **jQuery.ajax( url [, settings ] )**

Means both

```
jQuery.ajax( "www.google.com" )
```

and

```
jQuery.ajax( "www.google.com" , {dataType: 'mycustomtype'} )
```

are valid.